# How to pass a Variable through a session

Tags: php, variables, session

I know there are other posts about this, but I still can't seem to see where the code is incorrect.

I'm trying to pass a variable from one page to another via session: Below are the two pages; excuse some of the variable names as I was just plotting them in quickly.

main.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $_SESSION['itemId'] = $_POST['firstName'];
        echo "name = " . $_SESSION['itemId'];
    }
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 

    </head>
    <body>
       <form action="result.php" method="POST">
          First name: 
          <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit">
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

result.php

```
<?php
   session_start();

   echo $_SESSION['itemId'];

   session_destroy();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```

Previously I didn't have the unset in there. However, it hasn't made a difference.

The value is getting stored in the session, its just not passing it through to the other page.

Comment: Why u r unsetting session just after starting it?

Comment: remove that line and check it your code is perfect just remove session_unset(); line

Comment: remove the session unset function. Code will work fine

Comment: Thing is, I didn't have the unset there before and it still didn't work. I kept getting the error: "Undefined index: itemId in .... result.php". @BitsPlease

Comment: that is fine, you might have issues while setting up it...bt the line which u have written is clearly false not needed

Answer (score 0):

Main page should looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
//remove session_unset();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $_SESSION['itemId'] = $_POST['firstName'];
    echo "name = " . $_SESSION['itemId'];
}
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

</head>
<body>
   <form action="result.php" method="POST">
      First name: 
      <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
   </form>
```

Comment: I originally had the page like this, but it still didn't pass through the variable to the other page. (^ I've edited my originally post at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

remove session_unset(); line after start_session()
and why r u destroying session in result page.
if you want to destroy then 
store session value in variable

```
$id = $_SESSION['itemId'];
echo $id;
```

this code will help u